# Looking for differential diagnosis for Whirlpool Duet with multiple issues

Tags: appliances

We bought this washer in 2010. It's gotten light usage 2-3 loads a week.

Whirl Pool Model WFW9150ww00. This is one without a numeric display. Have to count flashes.

Some very odd behaviour:

From when it was young, it would give a 'too much soap' error, always on the extra rinse cycle. Unplug, wait 20 minutes. Run a rinse spin cycle, restart. Fine.  I've asked and answered a question about this 2 yr ago.

Lately we've been getting fill errors -- 6 minute not enough water.

And the GFI has been tripping.

This morning the door was unlocked while it had 3 inches of water above the front lip in it. Surprise!

Ok. Cleaned that up.

Pulled it out from the wall to tilt back to take off the lower front panel. Our suds problems seemed connected with trapped in the drain filter. One time I pulled 35 bucks in bills and coins out. (Note to Self: "Self, empty your pockets before tossing clothes in the wash.) This time a few small twigs and a bunch of dog hair.

Lowered it back down. Test with a rinse cycle. Fill is INCREDIBLY slow. Fails with slow fill.

Pull it back out. Take off hoses. Yes they have reasonable flow.

Put hoses back on. Repeat rinse cycle.

GFI trips.

Reset GFI

Repeat 3 times.

Turn power off immediately after GFI reset.

Set to different cycle.

Start.

Go back to slow fill.

Ok. There is a diagnostics paper in the front panel. Instructions say hit any set of 3 buttons 1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3 in 8 seconds to get into diagnostics mode.

Doesn't happen. Tried it half a dozen times with different combinations of power on, unplugging before,  unplugging for an hour to prevent state saving....

---

Option 1:

I have two valve failures. Unlikely.

I have a mainboard failure.

Something else.

Advice:

1. Are solenoids repairable?  Everyplace I look wants about 20% of the cost of a new washing machine for the two valves?
2. Differential diagnosis that explains:

   - Slow fill
   - GFI trips
   - Unlocked door with water
   - Non-responsive to diagnostics start sequence.

Comment: Three loads a week for 10 years?  I don't think that's light load.

Comment: Heavy use IMHO would be 3-4 loads a day for the same period.  Common in a farm family with several kids, some who work on the farm, or several preschool kids.